# How many ways are there for 5 men and 11 women to stand in a line where there are at least 2 men in a row?

Tags: combinatorics, factorial

I have a question from a textbook that I could not really understand what's going on. The question goes like this:

**How many ways are there for 5 men and 11 women to stand in a line where there are at least 2 men in a row?**

I know that it has something to do with permutation but for the life of me I couldn't find the solution.

Comment: I agree that you may genuinely have no idea how to solve the problem but in order to maintain this site has a repository of quality mathematical knowledge, you should read this: [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: From which textbook is this? If you have trouble solving a problem, try to find a simpler version of the same question (such as with smaller numbers). Then scale up to the larger case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HINT: It’s probably easiest to count the arrangements that do **not** have at least $2$ men in a row and subtract from the $16!$ possible arrangements.

- First line up the $11$ women; in how many ways can this be done?

The women determine $12$ possible locations for men: one at each end of the line, and $10$ more between adjacent women. Each of the $5$ men has to go into a different one of these locations.

- In how many ways can we pick $5$ of the $12$ possible locations?
- In how many ways can the $5$ men be arranged in those $5$ locations?

Now put the pieces together.

Comment: Is the answer $16!-5!\cdot 11!\cdot\Big[{10 \choose 3}+2{10 \choose 4}+{10 \choose 5}\Big]$?

Comment: @MatthewHolder: You’ve the right idea, but you’ve made it more complicated than it really is: your factor in square brackets should simply be $\binom{12}5$. You just have to choose any $5$ of the $12$ available slots.

Comment: lol I was determined to solve this problem using *stars and bars*. I try to solve these problems without peeking at the hints.